# Ordenar por coluna relacionamento polimórfico Laravel

Tags: laravel

Preciso ordenar os resultador pela coluna `distance` do relacionamento entre order e address paginando os resultados.

Order:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Address::class, 'addressable');
}
```

Address:

```
public function addressable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Tentei da forma abaixo mas não ordenou:

```
$orders = Order::with(['address' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('distance', 'asc');
}])->paginate(15)
```

Comment: Tenta `$query->orderBy('address.distance', 'asc');`

Comment: Unknown column 'address.distance'

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Para quem precisar, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
$orders = Order::with('address')->orderBy(function ($query) {
    $query->select('distance')
        ->from('addresses')
        ->whereColumn('addressable_id', 'orders.id')
        ->limit(1);
})->paginate(15);
```

Fonte: https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements?fbclid=IwAR3b6Yju4fRGpD8RnLt4Ncjx2cRfbDkoBYysR_-gscyZoAqJZWkFacCPTb8